# Clear the value in a datetimepicker field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm sure this is simple and it's my understanding of jquery/javascript that is holding me back - but I can't get this to work.

All I need to do - is - When a button on the screen is clicked, clear some of the input field on the form back to their original values.

This is working fine, for all fields except a datetimepicker field.

Here is the relevant bits of code, that defines the input field :

```
<div class='form-group' id='START_DATEFormGroup'>    
<label for='START_DATE' class='col-sm-2 control-label' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title=''>Start Date</label>
<div class='col-sm-8'>
<div class='input-group date form_date col-sm-3'  data-date-format='dd M yyyy' data-link-field='START_DATE' data-link-format='yyyy-mm-dd'>
<input class='form-control' size='16' type='text'  />
<input type='hidden' id='START_DATE' name='START_DATE' />
<span class='input-group-addon'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'>
</span> // group-addon
</span> // calendar
</div> // form_date
</div> // col-sm-8
</div> // form-group
```

I am initializing datetimepicker as follows :

```
function enableDatepicker(){
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
         $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd M yyyy',
            minView: 2,
            autoclose: 1,
            })
    });
}
```

To clear the input fields down I have :

```
function clearActionForm(){
     // code here to clear the various input fields to null or their initial values.
     // Need statements to clear the datetimepicker field to null.

}
```

So, can someone give me the line(s) of code I need to insert into clearActionForm() in order to clear the START_DATE field to null.

Thanks.

Comment: would `$('#START_DATE').val('')` work?

Comment: ah! Now - if I 'console.log(startDate.value)' BEFORE I run this line of code - I get the date back that I see on the screen. When I console.log AFTER this line of code - I get a null string. So this line of code has worked - however - it's not changed the value displayed on the screen to the user. Do I need to do an extra step to get the browser to update the value being displayed ?

Comment: `$('.form_date').datetimepicker('update','');`   Has no effect at all `$('.form_date').datetimepicker('update','2015-01-01');`  sets the date visible on the screen to 1st Jan 2015.    WHY doesn't the first one work - aarrggh

Comment: In the end. I gave up with `datetimepicker` - as I could not reset it to null. And wasn't using the "time" in this instance. So I've switched to datepicker and this statement works : `$('.form_date').datepicker('update','');`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the [eonasdan datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) use the following:

```
// clears
$("#form_date").data("DateTimePicker").date(null);

// updates with date
$("#form_date").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date());

// or update with string
var myCoolDate = "27 05 1975";
$("#form_date").data("DateTimePicker").date(myCoolDate);

// or update with a moment
 var moment = moment().add(2, 'd');
$("#form_date").data("DateTimePicker").date(moment);
```

Below is a demo of using different types of changes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd M YYYY',
  });
});

$('#clear').click(function() {
  $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date(null);
})

$('#date').click(function() {
  var sysdate = new Date();
  $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date());
})

$('#string').click(function() {
  var myCoolDate = "27 05 1975";
  $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date(myCoolDate);
})

$('#moment').click(function() {
  var now = moment().add(2, 'd');
  $("#datetimepicker1").data("DateTimePicker").date(now);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type='button' id='clear' Value='Clear Date'>
<input type='button' id='date' Value='Set with date'>
<input type='button' id='string' Value='Set with string'>
<input type='button' id='moment' Value='Set with moment'>
```

Comment: version : 4.17.47  - eonasdan  - $("#form_date").data("DateTimePicker").date(null); -- gives error in console

Comment: Thanks for this : `$("#form_date").data("DateTimePicker").date(null);`

Answer (score 8):

use this line `$('.form_date').data("DateTimePicker").clear()`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/B4BzK/465/)

Comment: This line gives the following error in the Web Console : TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined   I'm clearing doing something very wrong - none of these suggestions are working for me. (If I can ask a suplementary question )  My knowledge of JQuery is limited - I get that $('.form_date') is basically selecting all the items with the class form_date. I suspect clear() is a function to clear the item it's applied to - but what does "data('DateTimePicker') do ?

Comment: make sure you are using the same JS version that i have used in fiddle. and does the fiddle that i haved provided meets your requirement ? @RagD

Comment: @JSantosh, please update this.. http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/B4BzK/465/

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to rest the selected date as well as highlighted date by below concept

```
$('#txtWQApprovalDate').datepicker('setDate', null).datepicker('fill');
```

Comment: You are referring to the wrong api. That is [datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker), not [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the datetimepicker plugin from [xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), one quick way to clear the datetimepicker's current value would be the following:

```
$('.form_date').val('');
```

As an alternative (this sets the value of the datetimepicker to the current time):

```
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
  value: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
});
```

This value does not not match the format of the datetimepicker, but will be converted to the correct format automatically when the datetimepicker is used.

Comment: I'm  using bootstrap datetimepicker : https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/    I've tried these two options, and neither seem to work for me. I see no errors, or warning - nothing. It's doing my head in. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the eonasdan datetimepicker use the following:

```
// clears
$j(".form_date").data("DateTimePicker").setDate(null);

// updates to now
$j(".form_date").data("DateTimePicker").setDate(new Date());

// or update to a given date
var myCoolDate = "05/27/1975";
$j(".form_date").data("DateTimePicker").setDate(myCoolDate);
```

Comment: `setDate` does not exist as a function.